# Extract Method with continue

Tags: java, refactoring

We're refactoring a long method; it contains a long `for` loop with many `continue` statements.  I'd like to just use the **Extract Method** refactoring, but Eclipse's automated one doesn't know how to handle the conditional branching.  I don't, either.

Our current strategy is to introduce a `keepGoing` flag (an instance variable since we're going to want to **extract method**), set it to false at the top of the loop, and replace every continue with setting the flag to true, then wrapping all the following stuff (at different nesting levels) inside an `if (keepGoing)` clause.  Then perform the various extractions, then replace the `keepGoing` assignments with early returns from the extracted methods, then get rid of the flag.

Is there a better way?

**Update**: In response to comments - I can't share the code, but here's an anonymized excerpt:

```
private static void foo(C1 a, C2 b, C3 c, List<C2> list, boolean flag1) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        C4 d = null;
        Integer e = null;
        boolean flag2 = false;
        boolean flag3 = findFlag3(a, c);
        blahblahblah();
        if (e == null) {
            if (flag1) {
                if (test1(c)) {
                    if (test2(a, c)) {
                        Integer f = getF1(b, c);
                        if (f != null)
                            e = getE1(a, f);
                        if (e == null) {
                            if (d == null) {
                                list.add(b);
                                continue;
                            }
                            e = findE(d);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Integer f = getF2(b, c);
                        if (f != null)
                            e = getE2(a, f);
                        if (e == null) {
                            if (d == null) {
                                list.add(b);
                                continue;
                            }
                            e = findE(d);
                        }
                        flag2 = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (test3(a, c)) {
                        Integer f = getF2(b, c);
                        if (f != null)
                            e = getE2(a, f);
                        if (e == null) {
                            if (d == null) {
                                list.add(b);
                                continue;
                            }
                            e = findE(d);
                        }
                        flag2 = true;
                    } else {
                        if (d == null) {
                            list.add(b);
                            continue;
                        }
                        e = findE(d);
                        flag2 = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!flag1) {
                if (d == null) {
                    list.add(b);
                    continue;
                }
                e = findE(d);
            }
        }
        if (e == null) {
            list.add(b);
            continue;
        }
        List<C2> list2 = blahblahblah(b, list, flag1);
        if (list2.size() != 0 && flag1) {
            blahblahblah();
            if (!otherTest()) {
                if (yetAnotherTest()) {
                    list.add(b);
                    continue;
                }
                blahblahblah();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to post the code?

Comment: can you provide an abbreviated example?

Comment: Wow... I can certainly see why you want to refactor it.

Comment: Your code has quite much dead code, because for example "d == null" is always true. Here is a version with dead code removed: http://pastebin.com/m757a1134 In addition to that, you could remove the whole for loop and replace all continues with returns, because the body of the loop is executed only once. It's hard to refactor an anonymized method, because the semantics are not clear - you can't refactor the methods to use only one level of abstraction.

Comment: I'm amazed that Eclipse did not report all the unused variables and that some of those conditionals are always true/false. Maybe IDEA's code inspections are just so much better... or then you changed the semantics of the code when you anonymized it before posting it here

Comment: Thanks, Esko; the "unused" variables are just unused because the code in blahblahblah() uses them.  I can't share the actual code, and I felt that all that other stuff just detracted from the example.

Comment: I didn't even notice this comment before:  "can you provide an abbreviated example".  Kind of ironic considering the nature of the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is one of those fun ones where no single pattern will get you there.

I would work at it iteratively.

First I'd try to see if I couldn't use an early continue to remove one of those levels of ifs.  It's much clearer code to check for a condition and return early (or in your case continue) than to have deeply nested ifs.

Next I think I'd take some of the inner chunks and see if they couldn't be extracted into a separate method.  It looks like the first two big blocks (within the "if (test2(a, c)) {" and its else statement) are very similar.  There is cut and paste logic that should be the same.

Finally after that stuff is cleared up, you can start looking at your actual problem--you need more classes.  This entire statement is probably a three line polymorphic method in 3-5 sibling classes.

It's very close to throw-away and rewrite code, once you identify your actual classes, this entire method will vanish and be replaced with something so simple it hurts.  Just the fact that it's a static utility method should be telling you something--you don't want one of those in this type of code.

Edit (After looking a little more):
There is so much here it would be really fun to go through.  Remember that when you are done you want no code duplication--and I'm pretty sure this entire thing could be written without a single if--I think all your ifs are cases that could/should easily be handled by polymorphism.

Oh, and as an answer to your question of eclipse not wanting to do it--don't even TRY automatic refactoring with this one, just do it by hand.  The stuff inside that first if() needs to be pulled out into a method because it's virtually identical to the clause in its else()!

When I do something like this, I usually create a new method, move the code from the if into the new method (leaving just a call to the new method inside the if), then run a test and make sure you didn't break anything.

then go line by line and check to ensure there is no difference between the if and its else code.  If there is, compensate for it by passing the difference as a new variable to the method.  After you're sure everything is identical, replace the else clause with a call.  Test again.  Chances are at this point a few additional optimizations will become obvious, you'll most likely lose the entire if by combining it's logic with the variable you passed to differentiate the two calls.

Just keep doing stuff like that and iterating.  The trick with refactoring is to use Very Small Steps and test between each step to ensure nothing changed.

Comment: Yes, this is the type of code that is hard for random people on the Internet to do anything about. It really requires more knowledge of the problem, and more time and patience than I'm willing to put forth.

Comment: Having good tests in place is a must before touching code like that! Then you can work with it step by step, and undo your last step if it breaks the tests.

Comment: I must agree, if I understand correctly the current code is basically a DoItAll method with loads of arguments. Perhaps you should do a step back to what goal this method fulfills. Define possible input and expected output (maybe write a test on it if it's complex). Then decide if one, two or many methods are required and if all the functionality should be contained within this specific class.

Comment: I think you are considering a specific instance of DI.  Text file is the goal, but the code you posted is, unless I'm mistaken, already DI.  Even if you can't use an actual DI toolkit,  you're close enough to it that I think learning all you can about existing DI products will benefit you even if you roll your own dynamic version.

Answer (score 4):

`continue` is basically an analogue of an early return, right?

```
for (...) {
    doSomething(...);
}

private void doSomething(...) {
    ...
    if (...)
        return; // was "continue;"
    ...
    if (!doSomethingElse(...))
        return;
    ...
}

private boolean doSomethingElse(...) {
    ...
    if (...)
        return false; // was a continue from a nested operation
    ...
    return true;
}
```

Now I must admit that I didn't quite follow your current strategy, so I might have just repeated what you said. If so, then my answer is that I can't think of a better way.

Comment: I think using return statements in the extracted methods will work the same way as using continue in the main loop. Recently I faced the same issue in one of my project where I was refactoring the code. 

I can assure you that it was not as complicated as this one.

Answer (score 2):

If I were faced with your situation I would look at using other refactoring techniques such as "replace conditional with polymorphism".  That said you should always do one thing at a time, so if you first want to extract method you have two options:

1. Add the "keepGoing" flag
2. Throw an exception from the method

Of these two options, I think the keepGoing flag is better.  I wouldn't stop refactoring after you extract the method.  I am sure once you have a smaller method you will find a way to remove this flag and have cleaner logic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to summarize the answers here, while accepting Bill K's answer as the most complete.  But everyone had something good to offer, and I might use any of these approaches next time I'm faced with this sort of situation.

---

**mmyers**: Cut out the loop body, paste it into a new method and replace all the `continue`s with `return`s.  *This worked very nicely, although it would have trouble if there were other control flow statements, like break and return, inside the loop.*

---

**Bill K**: Tease it apart iteratively; look for duplication and eliminate it.  Take advantage of polymorphic classes to replace the conditional behavior.  Use Very Small Steps.  *Yes; this is all good advice, with broader applicability than just this specific case.*

---

**Aaron**: Either use the `keepGoing` flag to replace the `continue` or throw an Exception.  *I didn't try this, but I think the Exception option is a very nice alternative, and one I hadn't considered.*